# No muestra resultado del print por consola en python y vscode

Tags: python, linux, vscode

Estoy empezando a practicar con Python y me encuentro con el problema que no imprime el resultado del print por consola. El código es el siguiente:

```
print("###EJEMPLO WHILE###")
numero_usuario = int(input("Ingrese un número para generar la tabla de multiplicar: "))

if numero_usuario < 1:
    numero_usuario = 1

    print(f"Tabla del " + numero_usuario)

    contador = 1
    while contador <= 10:
        print(f"{numero_usuario} x {contador} = {numero_usuario*contador}")
        contador += 1
    else:
        print("Fin de la tabla")
```

Estoy usando Pop_OS 20.04 como SO y VSCode, que podria ser?

Comment: El primer print, el del titulo, ese si te sale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en tu primera condición, estás evaluando si `numero_usuario` es menor que uno y asignándole el valor de uno si fuese así lo cuál está bien, sin embargo, también estás haciendo que toda la lógica dependa de esta condición, por lo tanto, si el número es mayor que uno no se ejecutará tu código porque no cumple la condición... Limita el alcance de tu `if`, así:

```
print("###EJEMPLO WHILE###")
numero_usuario = int(input("Ingrese un número para generar la tabla de multiplicar: "))

if numero_usuario < 1:
    numero_usuario = 1

print(f"Tabla del {numero_usuario}")##Corregí esto también, ya que el operador + es para string y numero_usuario es un entero

contador = 1
while contador <= 10:
    print(f"{numero_usuario} x {contador} = {numero_usuario*contador}")
    contador += 1
else:
    print("Fin de la tabla")
```

¡Suerte programando!

Comment: No sabia que la indentación en Python era importante. Funcionó perfecto!

Comment: ¡Es muy importante! Define el alcance de tus funciones y bloques. Yo también me llevé la misma sorpresa hace años cuando programaba en C++ y descubrí python.